# My sql query returns same data type for 3 rows in json response

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am getting the same value for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd rows in my json response. The supposed result for the 2nd row displays in the second column and the 3rd result supposed in the 1st column displays in the 3rd. Ive tried everything and to change the query still no good. Thanks in advance

```
 $sql = "select
          e_name,
          a_shortcut,
          case
            when t_rank = 1 then '1st'
            when t_rank = 2 then '2nd'
            when t_rank = 3 then '3rd'
          end as t_rank
        from
          team inner join event on team.EID = event.eid Where e_type = 'nonsport' group by event.eid";                         

         $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


         $response = array();

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        array_push($response, array("e_name"=>$row[0],"1st"=>$row[1], 
        "2nd"=>$row[2], "3rd"=>$row[2]));

        } 
        echo json_encode (array("nresults"=>$response));
```

Here is what im getting in my server response if my 2nd and 3rd rows are [2] and [2].

```
 {"nresults":[{"e_name":"Amateur Photography Contest","1st":"AAA","2nd":"3rd","3rd":"3rd"}]}
```

If i changed

```
1st"=>$row[1], 
        "2nd"=>$row[2], "3rd"=>$row[2] into 1st"=>$row[1], 
        "2nd"=>$row[1], "3rd"=>$row[1]
```

It becomes like this

```
{"nresults":[{"e_name":"Amateur Photography Contest","1st":"AAA","2nd":"AAA","3rd":"AAA"}]}
```

My expected output is. Where AAA is rank 1, BBB is 2 and CCC is 3

like this

```
{"nresults":[{"e_name":"Amateur Photography Contest","1st":"AAA","2nd":"BBB","3rd":"CCC"}]}
```

Comment: Which column is '1st' in the query?

Comment: Get rid of all the non-MySQL stuff and see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @DaniloBustos 1st 2nd and 3rd should be the a_shortcut, depending on their ranks

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$sql = "select
          e_name,
          a_shortcut,
          GROUP_CONCAT(case when t_rank = 1 then  a_shortcut end separator ',') as rank1,
          GROUP_CONCAT(case when t_rank = 2 then  a_shortcut end separator ',') as rank2,
          GROUP_CONCAT(case when t_rank = 3 then  a_shortcut end separator ',') as rank3
        from
          team inner join event on team.EID = event.eid Where e_type = 'nonsport' group by event.eid";                         

         $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name); 

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


         $response = array();

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        //$ar=explode(',',$row['group_con']);
        array_push($response, array("e_name"=>$row[0],"1st"=>$row['rank1'], 
        "2nd"=>$row['rank2'], "3rd"=>$row['rank3']));

        } 
        echo json_encode (array("nresults"=>$response));
```

Comment: {"e_name":"Yell Competition","First":"1st","Second":"1st","Third":"3rd"}]} why i get this sir? i get it into 1 object, but different data